# allocating memory in an account and reading / writing to an array. "Not all bytes read"

Tags: solana-program, rust

I want to write the following structure to the account:

```
#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Clone, Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct Bid {
    /// XJUST lamports
    pub xjust: u64,
    /// selected side
    pub side: u8,
    /// user key
    pub pubkey: String,
}

#[derive(BorshDeserialize, BorshSerialize, Debug, Default)]
pub struct BidData {
    // list bids
    pub bids: Vec<Bid>,
}
```

allocate memory:

```
class Bid {
  xjust = new BN('10000000');
  side = 0;
  pubkey = "";
  constructor(fields: { xjust: BN, side: number, pubkey: string } | undefined = undefined) {
    if (fields) {
      this.xjust = fields.xjust;
    }
  }
}

class BettingAccount extends Bid {
  static decode(bytes: Buffer) {
    const dataLengthBuffer = Buffer.alloc(4);
    bytes.copy(dataLengthBuffer, 0, 0, 4);

    const dataLength = DataLength.decode(dataLengthBuffer);

    const accountDataBuffer = Buffer.alloc(Object.keys(dataLength).length);
    bytes.copy(accountDataBuffer, 0, 4, Object.keys(dataLength).length);
    return deserialize(BettingSchema, BettingAccount, accountDataBuffer);
  }
}

const BettingSchema = new Map([
  [Bid, {kind: 'struct', fields: [
    ['xjust', 'u64'],
    ['side', 'u8'],
    ['pubkey', 'string'],
  ]}],
  [BettingAccount, {kind: 'struct', fields: [
    ['bids', [Bid]]
  ]}]
]);
///.......
const transaction = new Transaction().add(
    SystemProgram.createAccountWithSeed({
      fromPubkey: newBet.publicKey,
      basePubkey: newBet.publicKey,
      seed: 'GREETING_SEED',
      newAccountPubkey: greetedPubkey,
      lamports,
      space: 10200,
      programId: PROGRAM_ID.publicKey,
    }),
  );
  await sendAndConfirmTransaction(connection, transaction, [newBet]);
  console.log("newbet", greetedPubkey.toString());
```

But when popyki count (even empty) account. i get
`failed: Failed to serialize or deserialize account data: Unknown'`

read account like this:

```
let mut bet_data = BidData::try_from_slice(&bet_account.data.borrow())?;
```

if i try

```
let mut bet_account = BidData::try_from_slice(&bet.data.borrow()[..]).unwrap();
```

then I get an error: `` panicked at \'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Custom { kind: InvalidData, error: "Not all bytes read" }\', src/lib.rs:94:83' ``

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that, as a variable length data block due to the `Vec<Bid>` which is not completely populating the account size you have pre-allocated.

What borsh does is look at the size of the account you've allocated and does a check to validate that the data array is completely consumed with data.

On the client side, borsh has a `deserializeUnchecked` to use instead.